# Powershell script to copy file named 'dat' from multiple folders

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I am trying to copy a file named 'dat'. This file has no extension. The thing is though that under a Parent Folder 'Personal' I have 500 folders and all of these 500 folders have the 'dat' file. I am interested in copying all these 'dat' files and placing them in my destination directory.

So when I paste these 'dat' files in my destination directory, I am hoping to name them as follows:

"Folder_they_were_residing_in.dat"

So all the dat files will be renamed to the folder_name they were residing under with the extension'dat'.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are the 500 folders all in the root of "personal" or are can they be nested within eachother?

Comment: They are all under "Personal". The directory structure looks like below: PS L:\usr\PersonalFolders> tree
Folder PATH listing for volume J:
L:.
├───133MHz00000001
├───166MHz
├───2.5V drivers
├───2.5V Standards
├───2006 SanFrancisco
├───200MHz frontside bus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure `$source` and `$dest` as needed, include trailing slash.

```
$source = "H:\personal\"
$dest   = "H:\archive\"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $source |
    Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Name -eq "dat" } |
        ForEach-Object { $_.CopyTo( $( $dest + $_.Directory.Name + ".dat" ), $true ) }
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
PS H:\> foreach($_ in Get-ChildItem dat -Recurse) { Copy-Item $_.Fullname H:\dest\$($_.Directory.ToString().Split("\")[-1])`.dat }
```

Comment: Neat, I've used ` for lots of other things, but never to escape the object.property syntax. +1.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for you too because let's have a happy Powershell party. :)